# Why is $\beta: \Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}$ continuous?

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

Let $a \in [0, \infty[$. Define
$$\beta: \Bbb{C}\to \Bbb{C}: z \mapsto \begin{cases}z, &|z| \leq a \\  a \operatorname{sign}(z), &|z| > a\end{cases}$$

Why is $\beta$ continuous?

Attempt:

If $a= 0$, then $\beta(z) = 0$, so we may assume $a \neq 0$. Note that if $|z| = a$ we have $a \operatorname{sign}(z) = a z/|z| = z$, so by the pasting lemma it suffices to check that
$$\beta\vert_{\{|z| \geq a\}}, \beta\vert_{\{|z| \leq a\}}$$ are continuous. However, this is trivial. Hence, $\beta$ is continuous.

Is the above correct?

Comment: What is $\mathrm{sign}(z)$ ? Is it $z/|z|$ ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Yes, and $0$ if $z = 0$.

Comment: 1.  That's an interesting use of the function "$\text{sign }z$.  2.  Just use the definition of continuity.  Your function satisfies it.  3.  Where is pasting lemma defined?

Comment: @mjw (1) It is fairly standard: See Axler's book on measure theory, Donald Cohn's measure theory book, (2) How? (3) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma

Comment: Your answer is fine now, and so I have deleted mine.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I do like alternative answers. You can undelete it so I can upvote it :)

Comment: I have undeleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is a good one, although I wouldn't say: "However, this is trivial" at the place that you did. The reason is that your presentation is a bit unclear, i.e. you didn't explain what's the point of checking that $z = a\operatorname{sign}{z}$ for $|z| = a$.

What I would add is that it shows that the formula $\beta(z) = a\operatorname{sign}{z}$ is valid even for $|z|\geq a$, and not just $|z|>a$. Also, I would add why these restrictions are continuous: the identity is obvious, while the other restriction is a product of continuous functions.

Finally, $\mathbb C$ is the union of the two closed subsets on which $\beta$ is continuous when restricted to and therefore, the pasting lemma applies.

Comment: Thank you for this perfect response!

Answer (score 1):

What you did is fine. Here's an alternative approach.

If $a=0$, then $\beta$ is the null function, which is continuous everywhere.

Assume now that $a\ne0$. Then $\beta$ is continuous at $0$ since, near $0$, $\beta(z)=z$. And, if $z_0\ne0$, $\beta$ is continuous at $z_0$, since $\beta(z)=az|z|^{-1}$ which, outside $0$, is the product of continuous functions. In particular, $\beta$ is continuous at $z_0$.

Comment: But is my approach correct as well?

Comment: No. What do $z\geqslant a$ and $z\leqslant a$ mean?

Comment: The modulus was missing. Edited.